# Ctrl-C and SSH command

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-server, sigint

I am trying to make an alias to easily run Jupyter on a remote machine. To this end, I concocted this command:

```
ssh -L 5542:localhost:5542 remote \
  'cd ipython && .direnv/python-3.8.10/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 5542'
```

This works perfectly... except for one thing: <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in the terminal does not seem to reach the `jupyter-notebook` process (which asks for two <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> presses to shut down cleanly). Instead it seems to stop the shell process and close the connection, orphaning `jupyter-notebook` instead of shutting it down.

I tried writing a shell script to wrap the above command (though I would really prefer to just pass the whole thing as a `ssh` argument), and even tried to trap `SIGINT`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$HOME/ipython"
foo() {
  echo break
}
trap foo SIGINT

.direnv/python-3.8.10/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 5542
```

but `ssh remote run-jupyter.sh` resulted in the same behaviour: just `^C`, terminated connection, orphaned `jupyter-notebook`. Notably, no `break` output. So maybe the <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> shuts down my `ssh` client?

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it so <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is correctly passed to `jupyter-notebook`?

(Obviously, I know I can shut down Jupyter from the webclient menu, and it will work correctly; but this is beside the point.)

The environment:

- `localhost` is Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1, running GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0) under Terminal 2.13 (447)
- `remote` is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, running GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When I just log in and invoke Jupyter from the resulting shell, it works; it hints that the difference is in whether the process has a terminal or not. This led me to the `-t` option for `ssh`, forcing the allocation of the terminal even when `ssh` is executing a command. This is the final command that works as expected:

```
ssh -tL 5542:localhost:5542 remote \
  'cd ipython && .direnv/python-3.8.10/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 5542'
```

Answer (score 0):

The local ssh process is (most likely) getting SIGINT when CTRL-C is pressed.

You can try changing the local shell process to not interpret the CTRL-C itself using `stty` like this:

```
stty intr ctrl-x
```

Note this remaps ctrl-x as the interrupt key, so now ctrl-c is treated as an ordinary input locally.  Whether this works or not depends on the remote handling of the raw ctrl-c.

Comment: This seems to shift the problem. Ctrl-C now does nothing (including in the remote shell), and Ctrl-X behaves like Ctrl-C did. I still have no way to cleanly exit the `jupyter-notebook` process from the terminal.